# 4 questions about processor architecture. (Computer engineering)

Tags: memory, virtual, processor

Our teachers has asked us around 50 true of false questions in preparation for our final exam. I could find an answer for most of them online or by asking relative. How ever, those 4 questions adrive driving me crazy. Most of those question aren't that hard, I just cant get any satisfying answer anywhere. Sorry, the original question are not written in english, i had to translate them myself. If you don't understand something, please tell me.
Thanks!

True or false

1. The size of the manipulated address by the processor determines the size of the virtual memory. How ever, the size of the memory cache is independent.
2. For long, DRAM technology stayed imcompatible with CMOS technology used to do the standard logic in processor. This is the reason DRAM memory is (most of the time) used outside of the processor (on a different chip).
3. Pagination let correspond multiple virtual addressing space to a same space of physical addressing.
4. An associative cache memory with sets of 1 line is an entierly associative cache memory, because one memory block can go in any set since each sets are of the same size that of the block.

Comment: Do you perchance have a textbook? I realize it's not as fast as Google, but you *usually* teachers use one...

Comment: What do you think are the answers, and why?

Comment: In 1, the size of the memory cache is independent from what, the virtual memory size or the address width?

Comment: Actually we have no textbook. We have some very short powerpoint slide but they're is nothing very interresting in them. I asked the teacher about where i could find answers for those question and he told me to search online.

Comment: I think the first answer would be mostly true except that i think that the length of the address would only give us the maximum size of the memory and not the actual size.
for the second answer i really have no idea, but the answer Karl Knechtel gave makes a lot of sens.
QUestion 3 : I might be possible to join multiple virtual addressing space to the same physical space but I really see no use in doing that.
Question 4 : Wikipedia is telling me that A true set-associative cache tests all the possible ways simultaneously. But i see no relation with what is written in the question

Answer (score 1):

1. "Manipulated address" is not a term of the art.  You have an m-bit virtual address mapping to an n-bit physical address.  Yes, a cache may be of any size up to the physical address size, but typically is much smaller.  Note that cache lines are tagged with virtual or more typically physical address bits corresponding to the maximum virtual or physical address range of the machine.
2. Yes, DRAM processes and logic processes are each tuned for different objectives, and involve different process steps (different materials and thicknesses to lay down DRAM capacitor stacks/trenches, for example) and historically you haven't built processors in DRAM processes (except the Mitsubishi M32RD) nor DRAM in logic processes.  Exception is so-called eDRAM that IBM likes to use for their SOI processes, and which is used as last level cache in IBM microprocessors such as the Power 7.
3. "Pagination" is what we call issuing a form feed so that text output begins at the top of the next page.  "Paging" on the other hand is sometimes a synonym for virtual memory management, by which a virtual address is mapped (on a page by page basis) to a physical address.  If you set up your page tables just so it allows multiple virtual addresses (indeed, virtual addresses from different processes' virtual address spaces) to map to the same physical address and hence the same location in real RAM.
4. "An associative cache memory with sets of 1 line is an entierly associative cache memory, because one memory block can go in any set since each sets are of the same size that of the block."

Hmm, that's a strange question.  Let's break it down.  1) You can have a direct mapped cache, in which an address maps to only one cache line.  2) You can have a fully associative cache, in which an address can map to *any* cache line; there is something like a CAM (content addressible memory) tag structure to find which if any line matches the address.  Or 3) you can have an n-way set associative cache, in which you have, essentially, n sets of direct mapped caches, and a given address can map to one of n lines.  There are other more esoteric cache organizations, but I doubt you're being taught them.

So let's parse the statement.  "An associative cache memory".  Well that rules out direct mapped caches.  So we're left with "fully associative" and "n-way set associative".  It has sets of 1 line.  OK, so if it is set associative, then instead of something traditional like 4-ways x 64 lines/way, it is n-ways x 1 lines/way.  In other words, it is fully associative.  I would say this is a true statement, except the term of the art is "fully associative" not "entirely associative."

Makes sense?

Happy hacking!

Comment: If a cache *set* has only one block, then there is only one *way* (i.e., direct-mapped). Of course, one would not usually say "one-way associative cache", but this *might* be a translation issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. True, more or less (it depends on the accuracy of your translation I guess :) ) The number of bits in addresses sets an upper limit on the virtual memory space; you could, of course, choose not to use all the bits. The size of the memory cache depends on how much actual memory is installed, which is independent; but of course if you had more memory than you can address, then it still can't be used.
2. Almost certainly false. We have RAM on separate chips so that we can install more without building a whole new computer or replacing the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no a-priori upper or lower limit to the cache size, though in a real application certain sizes make more sense than others, of course.
2. I don't know of any incompatibility. The reason why we use SRAM as on-die cache is because it's faster.
3. Maybe you can force an MMUs to map different virtual addresses to the same physical location, but usually it's used the other way around.
4. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks AndreKR. This makes a lot of sens.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, #2 here is incorrect.  Logic and DRAM processes are optimized for different purposes and you rarely see processors made in DRAM processes or DRAM made in logic/processor processes.